# How to fix unexpected token u in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have asp.net mvc 4 project where try to implement autocomplete but have an error: unexpected token u. I know that this mean that I have unidentified object but dont understand what I should to do. Anybody can help me?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm("FilterEquipment", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field" style="float: left; padding-top: 2px; padding-right: 10px;">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchQuery)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchQuery)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

<script>

    request();
    function request() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetListofNames", "Home")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {}
        }).success(function (data) {
            var responseArray = JSON.parse(data.d);//here is an error
            $("#SearchQuery").autocomplete({
                source: responseArray
            });

        })
            .fail(function (e) {
                alert("Error");
            });
    }
</script>

public JsonResult GetListofNames() {
            var companies = _equipmentRepo.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            var oJss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            String strResponse = oJss.Serialize(companies);
            return Json(strResponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And here is my responce:

```
"[\"utyutu\",\"qweqweqweqweqwe\",\"йцуйцуqweqeasdzxc\",\"zxc\",\"dfg\",\"vbn\",\"mbm\",\"hjgkjgйцуйу\",\"йцуцй\",\"йцу\",\"йцуйцуйцуфыв\",\"ячсмям\",\"йцуйцуцу\",\"йцуйцуцу\",\"йцуйцуцу\",\"йцуйцуцу\"]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is getting serialized twice.. Once by the `JavaScriptSerializer`, and once in the `Json()` method. Try this:

```
    public JsonResult GetListofNames() {
        var companies = _equipmentRepo.GetAll().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
        return Json(companies, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the json response after making that change?

Comment: And if the json response is the same, are you sure the response isn't being cached?

Comment: This is not the same 0: "utyutu"
1: "qweqweqweqweqwe"
2: "йцуйцуqweqeasdzxc"
3: "zxc"
4: "dfg"
5: "vbn"
6: "mbm"
7: "hjgkjgйцуйу"
8: "йцуцй"
9: "йцу"
10: "йцуйцуйцуфыв"
11: "ячсмям"
12: "йцуйцуцу"
13: "йцуйцуцу"
14: "йцуйцуцу"
15: "йцуйцуцу"
ConsoleSearchEmulationRendering

Comment: But issue the same undefined

Comment: I'm sure that response isn't cached.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example, you are serializing it and it not required.

[a link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/746697/Auto-Complete-Using-jQuery-and-ASP-NET-MVC)!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.